# Truncating labels on a radio button swatch

Tags: radio-buttons, ux-writing, truncation

I have an ecommerce project wherein there's a limitation on the displayed text inside the radio button for swatches. This is a requirement of our business analyst and said that it was good but there would be an issue on the mobile experience. Would like to ask for a help if what are the other work arounds for this design.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try a dropdown.

This way you avoid the mobile use case problems, as it's another means of allowing only one item to be in a selected state but can fit in a mobile situation.

- Select... shows the user that nothing has been chosen yet
- You don't have to truncate
- You can use a checkmark to emphasize the selection inside the menu
- It scales if you add more choices
- No need to rely on tooltips

[image]

##### Update: If you must use selectable buttons, you can stack them if space is an issue.

If you have no choice but to use the buttons, you could allow them to stack into multiple lines. If space is limited, you can have them flow to the fewest vertical rows, as the example below.

- This is not an elegant solution, but it keeps the whole label visible

[image]

- If you have more vertical space, you could stack them into 4 rows, but keep the full width, so the longest title determines the width:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike! This means a lot. But we currently have the dropdown menu already and our BA said to make a radio button so that the user would have a choice to weather use the radio button or the dropdown in the configuration panel. By this, it means I needed to create a design for radio button and have to consider the long label, is there a possibility where I could apply the truncation of label here? If yes, I would like to know how will it look like. Thanks!

Comment: @JhopatSantiago I've updated my answer. An alternative is to use selectable buttons, but allow them to stack. It's not my first choice, but you preserve legibility.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Mike! These suggestion would be helpful :)